# MySQL query Select, SUM, LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sum, left-join

Table1 named **stock** contains column **Items**
Table2 named **Products_sold** contains **Items, Quantity**
Table3 named **products_purchased** contains **Items, Quantity**

I need sql query that gets three columns such as

(Products) (all items from table 1)
(Products sold) (sum of quantity of each items from product_sold table)
(Products purchased) (sum of quantity of each items from product_purchased table)

I have query but it does not work correctly

```
  Select stock.Items as Products, 
         SUM(Products_sold.Quantity) as [Products Sold], 
         SUM(Products_purchased.Quantity) as [Products purchased]
  From 
         (
           (Stock LEFT JOIN products_purchased ON stock.Items=products_purchased.Items) 
           LEFT JOIN products_sold ON stock.Items=products_sold.Item
         )
  Group By stock.Items
```

Comment: Edit your question with your attempts to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT S.Items as Products, 
       COALESCE(PS.Quantity, 0) as [Products Sold], 
       COALESCE(PP.Quantity, 0) as [Products purchased]
From Stock S 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Items, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity 
           FROM products_purchased 
           GROUP BY Items
         ) AS PP ON S.Items = PP.Items 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Items, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity 
           FROM products_sold 
           GROUP BY Items
         ) AS PS ON S.Items = PS.Items;
```