# The data source object is invalid

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I got this error! When open crystal report upon follong code.

The data source object is invalid.

Code is here

```
Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            CrystalReport2 rpt = new CrystalReport2();
            obj.connection();
            String accept = "SELECT S.Product as Products, COALESCE(Pur_Orders.Quantity, 0) as [Products purchased], COALESCE(Sale_Orders.Quantity, 0) as [Products Sold] From Inv_stock S LEFT JOIN (SELECT Item, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity FROM Pur_Orders Where Pur_Orders.Date='" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date + "' GROUP BY Item) AS Pur_Orders ON S.Product = Pur_Orders.Item LEFT JOIN (SELECT Item, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity FROM Sale_Orders Where Sale_Orders.Date='" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date + "' GROUP BY Item) AS Sale_Orders ON S.Product = Sale_Orders.Item";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(accept, obj.con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Inv_stock");
            da.Fill(ds, "Pur_Orders");
            da.Fill(ds, "Sale_Orders");
            rpt.SetDataSource(da);
            obj.con.Close();
            Inventory inv = new Inventory();
            inv.CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = rpt;
            inv.Visible = true;
```

What is problem?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the datasource of the report with DataAdapter:

> > rpt.SetDataSource(da);

Replace it with a dataset or a datatable like this:

> > rpt.SetDataSource(ds);  // a dataset
> >
> > rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["TableName"]);  // a datatable

Comment: I did but get undesired results in crystal report.
please provide me full code, i am beginner.

Comment: So what exactly are you doing? What kind of undesired results?

Comment: I want these results in crystal report
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638014/mysql-query-select-sum-left-join?noredirect=1#comment43694780_27638014

Comment: First check if your SQL command is correct? And, use only one line of `da.Fill(ds, "NewTableName");`... give a new table name. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You should make a View  of the Nested Query and Check it and then call that specific view when u are making a new Report as Datasourse.
If your Query is Correct but Datasourse is invalid you will  not get you Desired output on the Report..